# Десериализация из xml двух пересекающихся списков

Tags: java, xml, list, jackson, десериализация

Пытаюсь прочитать следующую структуру `xml`:

```xml
<root>
    <foo name="AAA" />
    <bar name="BBB" />
    <foo name="CCC" />
    <bar name="DDD" />
</root>
```

Классы `java`:

```java
public class Foo { // public class Bar {...
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String name;
    // getters + setters + constructor
}
```

```java
public class Root {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "foo")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Foo> foos;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "bar")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Bar> bars;
    // getters + setters + constructor
}
```

Читаю `xml` следующим образом:

```java
System.out.println(new XmlMapper().readValue(xml, Root.class));
```

Но в результате почему-то пропадают объекты "AAA" и "BBB":

```
Root(foos=[Foo(name=CCC)], bars=[Bar(name=DDD)])
```

Причём, если упорядочить элементы в исходном `xml`: сначала `foo`, потом `bar`, - тогда все объекты читаются нормально:

```
Root(foos=[Foo(name=AAA), Foo(name=CCC)], bars=[Bar(name=BBB), Bar(name=DDD)])
```

Использую [jackson-dataformat-xml](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.11/overview-summary.html) 2.11.2, последнюю на текущий момент.

Что здесь происходит? Как это исправить?

---

<sup>Свободный перевод вопроса: [«Jackson XML deserialization skips field when using multiple useWrapping = false»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63220292/11141611) от участника [@michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898563/michael).</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для любого логического свойства [JacksonXmlProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html) можно указать метод [JsonSetter](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.11.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html) или [JsonGetter](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.11.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonGetter.html) - это может оказаться проще, чем писать собственный `Deserializer` / `Serializer` для всего класса. Ещё есть аннотация [JsonAnySetter](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.11.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html), которую можно использовать как резервный вариант для чего-то, что не указано в вашем классе, например, можно поместить все XML-атрибуты элемента в одну карту, а не указывать свойства для каждого возможного атрибута.

---

В данном случае для десериализации элементов двух списков в классе `Root` нужно добавить кастомные сеттеры [JsonSetter](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.11.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html):

```java
@JsonSetter(value = "foo")
public void setFooFromXml(Foo foo) {
    if (this.foos == null) {
        this.foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    }
    this.foos.add(foo);
}

@JsonSetter(value = "bar")
public void setBarFromXml(Bar bar) {
    if (this.bars == null) {
        this.bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();
    }
    this.bars.add(bar);
}
```

```
Root(foos=[Foo(name=AAA), Foo(name=CCC)], bars=[Bar(name=BBB), Bar(name=DDD)])
```

---

<sup>При формировании ответа использовался [ответ на вопрос «Jackson XML deserialization skips field when using multiple useWrapping = false»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63347057/11141611) от участника [@jnorman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13909378/jnorman).</sup>